# How to use Java ExecutorService threadpool for ongoing/infinite tasks?

Tags: java, concurrency

The Java ExecutorService framework allows you to delegate a number of tasks to be performed using a managed thread pool so that N tasks can be performed X tasks at a time until complete.

My question is ... what if N is a number that is either infinite or so large as to be impractical to allocate/assign/define initially.

How can you leverage the concept of thread pooling in Java (ExecutorService) to handle more tasks than you could reasonably submit without exhausting resources.

For purposes of this answer, assume each task is self-contained and does not depend on any other task and that tasks can be completed in arbitrary order.

My initial attempt at attacking this problem involved feeding the ExecutorService Y threads at a time but I quickly realized that there's no apparent way to tell when a particular task is complete and therefore submit a new task to be executed.

I know I could write my own "ExecutorService" but I am trying to leverage the bounty of what the Java framework already provides.  I'm generally in the "don't re-invent the wheel" category because greater minds than mine have already made investments for me.

Thanks in advance to anybody that can provide any insight in how to attack this type of problem.

Comment: You may want to use something more complex such as the Quartz scheduler.

Comment: IIRC, `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n)` allows you to submit arbitrarily many tasks; as soon as one of the `n` threads finishes one task, it takes another from the queue that's waiting to be run.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: The question states that "N is a number that is either infinite or so large as to be impractical", so you cannot just submit all the tasks at once. The `ThreadPoolExecutor` class does allow you specify the size of the work queue and the behavior it should have when the queue is full, but that doesn't really help the very large task set case.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I agree.  My problem is that the number of tasks I need to queue is so large (might as well be infinite?) that said queue couldn't reasonably be stored in any running JVM.

Comment: If it helps I will attempt to rephrase the problem: I have an infinite number of tasks to perform.  Each task is self-contained so none of them need to wait/depend on any other task.  How do I maximize an implementation (in Java) so that each task is completed in the minimum amount of time/resources.  i.e. How do I achieve 100% CPU resources on an N-core machine when I have an infinite amount of tasks I need it to perform in the least amount of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `CompletionService` to do it. You can have one thread that seeds the service with a bunch of tasks, then as tasks complete you can add new ones.

A simple example:

```
final CompletionService service = new ExecutorCompletionService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5));
Runnable taskGenerator = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Seed the service
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            service.submit(createNewTask());
        }
        // As tasks complete create new ones
        while (true) {
            Future<Something> result = service.take();
            processResult(result.get());
            service.submit(createNewTask());
        }
    }
};
new Thread(taskGenerator).start();
```

This uses a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with 5 threads to process tasks and a hand-rolled producer/consumer thread for generating tasks and processing results.

Obviously you'll want something a little smarter than `while (true)`, you'll need to have sensible implementations of `processResult` and `createNewTask`, and this assumes that task execution is much slower than generating them or processing the results.

Hopefully this will get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor with java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue as its workQueue. This way attempt to put more tasks than the size of the queue would block.

```
  BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue=new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100);
  ThreadPoolExecutor tpe=new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 10, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue);

  while (true) {
     tpe.execute(createNewTask());
  }
```